# mediatR validation behaviour does not work

Tags: .net, validation, mediatr

I am building base project using MediatR. Somehow my validation behaviour does not work. Any help is appreciated.

here is my validation behavior class

```
public class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse?>
where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
where TResponse : BaseAPIResponse<TResponse>, new()
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators;

    public ValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        this.validators = validators;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse?> Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse?> next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!validators.Any())
        {
            return await next.Invoke();
        }

        var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(validators.Select(v => v.ValidateAsync(context, cancellationToken)));
        var failures = results.SelectMany(r => r.Errors).Where(f => f != null).ToList();

        if (!failures.Any())
        {
            return await next.Invoke();
        }

        var response = new BaseAPIResponse<TResponse>();
        response.ValidationErrors = new List<ValidationError>(failures.Select(x => new ValidationError { Key = x.PropertyName, Value = x.ErrorMessage }));
        response.SetErrorMessage("Please check for invalid values.");

        return await Task.FromResult(response as TResponse);
    }

}
```

here is how I registering

```
services.AddMediatR(x => x.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>));
services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestExceptionHandler<,,>), typeof(ExceptionHandlingBehavior<,,>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(LoggingBehavior<,>));
```

here is my command

```
public class CreateTestRecordCommand : IRequest<ProjectBase.Domain.Entities.Test>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class CreateTestRecordCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateTestRecordCommand, ProjectBase.Domain.Entities.Test>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork uow;

    public CreateTestRecordCommandHandler(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        this.uow = uow;
    }
    public async Task<Domain.Entities.Test> Handle(CreateTestRecordCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var record = new Domain.Entities.Test
        {
            Name = request.Name,
        };

        await uow.TestRepository.CreateAsync(record);
        await uow.CompleteAsync(cancellationToken);

        return record;
    }

    
}
```

finally here is my validator

```
public class CreateTestRecordCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateTestRecordCommand>
{
    public CreateTestRecordCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty().When(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name))
            .WithMessage("Please fill this field");
    }
}
```

I am giving empty string as input. When I debug the code does not hit ValidationBehavior class. Goes directly LoggingBehavior and then Repository

Comment: Your behavior has the following type constraint: `where TResponse : BaseAPIResponse<TResponse>, new()`. This means that the command's `TResponse`, which is `ProjectBase.Domain.Entities.Test`, must implement `BaseAPIResponse<Test>`. Is that the case? If not, that's the reason that the behavior is filtered out.; its not applicable to `CreateTestRecordCommandHandler`.